# Moving an ImageView with animation in Android?

Tags: button, imageview

I'm currently trying to develop a car game in which I have included 2 `Buttons`, that are Right and Left. When I click Left the car moves to left and I have achieved this by `car.setX(car.getX() - 10);` inside `onClick` of Left `Button`. It works but the car doesn't move continuously I've to click again and again to keep the car moving to left. What I want to achieve is the car should immediately start moving to left when I click Left `Button` and stop when I release the `Button`, as it's a game! Any ideas guys? Right now I'm making it work like this:

```
left.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                car.setX(car.getX() - 10);
            }

        });
```